# Pandas DF: Formatting Hyphenated Last Names

Tags: python, pandas, string, format

I'm building a python module to help me format text for work. I work with application and survey data that I'm importing into our company's CRM so I'm trying to turn something like " louis-dreyfus " into "Louis-Dreyfus" where the name is capitalized in the beginning and after the hyphen. My code worked when I wrote out the function in the same jupyter notebook that I imported the dataset into but when I write out the function in a module and import it, " louis-dreyfus " turns into "Louis-dreyfus". Here's my code so far:

```
def format_names(df_name, col_name):
    for idx, val in enumerate(df_name[col_name]):
        val = val.strip()
        if '-' in val:
            split = val.split('-')
            n1 = split[0].strip()
            n2 = split[1].strip()
            n1 = n1.capitalize()
            n2 = n2.capitalize()
            hyphen_names = n1 + '-' + n2 
            df_name[col_name].iloc[idx] = hyphen_names
```

If I print out df_name[col_name].iloc[idx] at the end of the "if" statement I get the correct output "Louis-Dreyfus" but it doesn't seem to replace the value in the dataframe. HELP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know about the efficiency but perhaps try

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = '''\
id,name
101,asdf-qwer
102,justin
103,foo-bar
104,bar-foo
105,was here
'''

f = StringIO(data)
df = pd.read_csv(f)

print(df)

df['name'] = df['name'].str.title()

print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

**Sample data:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'names':[" louis-dreyfus ", "some-name    ", "    another-more-complex-name   "]})
```

**Code:**

```
def format_names(s):
    return '-'.join([x.strip().capitalize() for x in s.split('-')])

df['names'].map(format_names)
```

**Result:**

```
# Out[10]: 
# 0                Louis-Dreyfus
# 1                    Some-Name
# 2    Another-More-Complex-Name
# Name: names, dtype: object
```

Comment: There's no need to create a function for that. You can just use `df['names'].map(str.title)`

Comment: @GabrielMelodePaula You are right, thank you for letting me know. I wasn't aware that title() works with hyphens as well, in that case it should even be possible to do just: `df['names'].str.title()`. On the other hand in his function kmm also does a `.strip()` after splitting, so " louis   -dreyfus " would be: "Louis-Dreyfus" which you cannot achive with title() alone.

Comment: Me neither, I just tested here and figured it out hahaha, but it's was great work around if it didn't

Comment: Thanks @GabrielMelodePaula for shortening the code. Got it working with:

df_name[col_name] = df_name[col_name].map(str.strip)
df_name[col_name] = df_name[col_name].map(str.title)

Comment: @kmm in this case you can simply do both by using `df_name[col_name] = df_name[col_name].str.strip(),str.title()` You could then consider accepting an answer to help future readers. Justins answer might be the closest then.